# Where can I access the bugs and freezes reports on the google android developer console?

Tags: android

I remember seeing it once but I can't find it anymore

edit: I mean here https://play.google.com/apps/publish/

I remember finding a report showing the number of crashes of an app and details. but i can't find it anymore

Comment: @ChiragRaval I've added more to the original post

Comment: There is one Error Link near published on right side . Click on that for particular applicaion . After Clicking on that you can find Application Error Reports . You can find that link after login into developer CONSOLE and you upload any application on market.

Comment: click the Error link near the published/un published on the right side of your app

Comment: @idaNakav I don't have such link. can you post the URL please

Comment: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=<Developer Account>#FeedbackOverviewPlace:p=<Package Name> just change the developer account and package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it on right side of you app amount in the google play console.Added the screenshot

[image]

**Link** - Find it [Here](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/Home?dev_acc=15218280837457536070)

Comment: I have recently unpublished my application. I guess this is why I don't see the errors link anymore. could you post the URL for it please

Comment: Edited the answer with the link.If you unpublished your app then you cant see the error link

Answer (score 1):

[image]On right side beside published icon a hyper link named Error, here if new error report came it will displayed like Errors(1) or else Errors

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean LogCat?

In eclipse go to Window > Show View > LogCat